# Spring boot starts even if start with nonexistent profile

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-profiles

I have **spring boot application** - `server.jar` with next structure:

```
-resources
 -application.yaml
```

After the build, I create a folder with a name `source`. And put my jar to this folder. Also, I create start `.bat` file

```
-source
 -server.jar
 -start.bat
```

In `start.but` the file I write next:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active="foofoofoo" -jar server.jar
pause
```

When I run `start.bat`  my server starts with log:

```
The following profiles are active: foofoofoo
```

And use properties from `application.yaml`. I have not profile with name `foofoofoo` and I have not `apllication-foofoofoo.yaml`. Why? Why spring writes that it loads `foofoofoo` profile, load `application.yaml` and work?

It must crash because I start the application with the nonexistent profile!

Instead, I see a running application with another property! How can I process this?

Comment: Does your application.yml have all the properties that application-your-profile.yml has?

Comment: @htshame I don't have any `application-your-profile.yml `. I have just `application.yml` in my jar

Comment: A profile specific properties file is optional. So not having it would not lead to crashing the application. The profile can be used for far more things then loading property files. So no a "missing" file won't crash the application because it simply is optional.

Comment: @ M. Deinum then how can I management profiles. I have an application with 3 profiles - `dev,test,prod`. And I have 4 `yaml ` files - `application.yaml`, `application-dev.yaml`, `application-test.yaml` and `application-prod.yaml`. I store base configs in `application.yaml` and override it in other yaml files. And when I start application in test enviroment I pass parameter - `-Dspring.profiles.active=test`. But if `application-test.yaml` does not exist - application start with `application.yaml`. It is not good

Comment: I want to prevent the application from running if it has not specific configurations

Answer (score 1):

When you start the application `application.yml` file in your `resources` directory is getting included **anyway**.

If you also have `application-yourProfileName.yml` in `resources` directory and add

`--spring.profile.active=yourProfileName` parameter,

then **both** property files are getting included, and **NOTE**  that in this case `application-yourProfileName.yml` override the same properties in `application.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

The profile can be used in more ways than just application's properties. It does not matter if you do not have `application-your-profile.{properties, yml}`. Loading profile does not mean loading properties file.